# Spring Data JPA [Unknown column '...' in 'where clause']

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I'm working on a Spring project, and MySQL database sysyem.

I have a table that has this column "list_id"
and I have in Java class this variable for this column. However the two name are diffrent as you can see:

```
    @Column(name = "list_id")
    private int listId;
```

and I'm making this query:

```
   @Query(value="select * from words_list WHERE list_id=listId", nativeQuery=true)
   List<WordList> neverTested(@RequestParam("listId") int listId);
```

and I try to get them in the controller class

```
    public List<WordList> neverTested(@RequestParam int listId){

    return wordListRepository.neverTested(listId);
}
```

I always get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'listId' in 'where clause'
```

even I'm sure of my way, but it sounds that the problem in the names

Comment: What is `@RequestParam` doing in the JpaRepository? Use `@Param` to bind the value to the sql statement. Also, you don't have to use `@Param` if you have `-parameters` compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ":" before listId, like this:

```java
 @Query(value="select * from words_list WHERE list_id = :listId", nativeQuery=true)
   List<WordList> neverTested(@RequestParam("listId") int listId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a colon before your parameter
like this

```
 @Query(value="select * from words_list WHERE list_id=:listId", nativeQuery=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [org.springframework.data.repository.query.@Param](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/Param.html) to pass method parameters to the query,
instead of [org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

@Query query string example:

```
"select * from words_list WHERE list_id=:listId"
```

named parameters are indicated in the query string by a colon followed by the parameter name.

example combining the @Query and @Param annotations:

```java
@Query(value="select * from words_list WHERE list_id=:listId", nativeQuery=true)
List<WordList> neverTested(@Param("listId") int listId);
```